# What does "animated" mean and/or used for?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, uitableview, animated

I see this used a lot however I'm not sure what it does.

```
animated:YES
```

or

```
animated:NO
```

For example in a viewDidLoad method I might have this code

```
self.tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = YES;
```

and in a viewWillAppear I might have this code

```
// some code here, and/or acondition is met, therefore put the tableview in editing mode

[self setEditing:YES animated:NO];
```

So again, what is `animated:NO` mean? And what is the difference between `animated:NO` and `animated:YES`? I do not see a visible and/or functional difference in my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS can animate many changes to on-screen user interface elements.  For example, if you open the Settings app on an iPhone or iPod, then tap the Brightness row, the Brightness page will slide onto the screen over about .25 seconds, instead of just instantaneously replacing the main Settings page.  This is an animated change to the user interface.  This particular animation happens when you send the `pushViewController:animated:` message to a `UINavigationController` with the `animated` parameter set to `YES`.

In the case of the `setEditing:animated:` message, you can see an example of the animated change by opening the Phone app, selecting the Recents tab, and touching the Edit button.  All of the rows slide to the right, hiding the disclosure buttons and revealing the delete buttons.  This change is animated over about .25 seconds because the `animated` parameter of the message was `YES`.  If the `animated` parameter were `NO`, the rows would change instantaneously to show the delete buttons and not show the disclosure buttons.

Comment: Great answer, thanks for the detailed explanation! PS - two questions comes to mind, is the `.25` seconds adjustable? And, does this have anything to do with `UITableViewRowAnimationFade`? Just wondering...

Comment: You might be able to change the .25 seconds using `+[CATransaction setAnimationDuration:]` or `+[UIView animateWithDuration:animations:]`, but I haven't tried it.  You use the `UITableViewRowAnimationFade` constant as the `animation` parameter in messages like `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`.